# Transaction API Order object with EUR currency

Tags: transactions, actions-on-google

I'm trying to create a cart with currency EUR but action still crash.
this is my sample order object

```
 "order": {
        "merchantOrderId": "rxhc",
        "createTime": "2020-07-07T09:11:19.906Z",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2020-07-07T09:11:19.906Z",
        "userVisibleOrderId": "rxhc",
        "contents": {
          "lineItems": [
            {
              "id": "yedf",
              "name": "USB cable",
              "priceAttributes": [
                {
                  "type": "REGULAR",
                  "name": "Item Price",
                  "state": "ACTUAL",
                  "amount": {
                    "currencyCode": "EUR",
                    "amountInMicros": 0
                  },
                  "taxIncluded": true
                },
                {
                  "type": "TOTAL",
                  "name": "Total Price",
                  "state": "ACTUAL",
                  "amount": {
                    "currencyCode": "EUR",
                    "amountInMicros": 0
                  },
                  "taxIncluded": true
                }
              ],
              "purchase": {
                "quantity": 1,
                "unitMeasure": {
                  "measure": 1,
                  "unit": "EUR"
                },
                "itemOptions": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

someone can help me with this?
If i change the currencyCode to "USD" and unit to "POUND" it work well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved removing unitMeasure object and changing currencyCode to "EUR"